# What are the benefits of using systemd?

Tags: upstart, systemd

Ubuntu has been using Upstart since the 6.10 release. It was a relatively simple and easy to manage the system and init, which allowed one to intuitively and quickly start and stop services on demand.

However, Ubuntu now ships with `systemd`, which seems more complicated for a simple task such as service and process management.

What useful features does `systemd` provide that the old Upstart model didn't or couldn't provide that made Ubuntu upgrading to it?

Comment: In my experience, the average user does not care about which system is used to manage anything on his/her computer. The above-average user who wants to get a grip on what's going on, can read for example [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) and [this (IMHO) good blog post](http://blog.jorgenschaefer.de/2014/07/why-systemd.html).

Comment: I think one goal was to establish a single init-system among all major linux distributions (these have, currently,  higher market share: ubuntu, centos, suse)

Answer (score 1):

By this point *(which is 3 years after the question been posted)* different wordings of this question have been asked so many times, that you can probably find much more detailed and interesting answers with a search engine. But, just so this question has an actual answer, let me quote one [from the unix.stackexchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6190/59928#what-are-the-pros-cons-of-upstart-and-systemd):

> Both upstart and systemd are attempts to solve some of the problems with the limitations of the traditional SysV init system.  For example, some services need to start after other services (for example, you can't mount NFS filesystems until the network is running), but the only way in SysV to handle that is to set the links in the rc#.d directory such that one is before the other.  Add to that, you might need to re-number everything later when dependencies are added or changed.  Upstart and Systemd have more intelligent settings for defining requirements.  Also, there's the issue with the fact that everything is a shell script of some sort, and not everyone writes the best init scripts.  That also impacts the speed of the startup.
>
> Some of the advantages of systemd I can see:
>
> - Every process started gets its own cgroup or a particular cgroup.
> - Pre-creation of sockets and file handles for services, similar to how xinetd does for it's services, allowing dependent services to start faster.  For example, systemd will hold open the filehandle for /dev/log for syslog, and subsequent services that send to /dev/log will have their messages buffered until syslogd is ready to take over.
> - Fewer processes run to actually start a service.  This means you aren't writing a shell script to start up your service.  This can be a speed improvement, and (IMO) something easier to set up in the first place.
>
> One disadvantage I know of is that to take advantage of systemd's socket/FH preallocation, many daemons will have to be patched to have the FH passed to them by systemd.

[The biggest myths](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/the-biggest-myths) blog post
about systemd also has this point:

> 8. **Myth: systemd was created as result of the NIH syndrome.**
>
> This is not true. Before we began working on systemd we were pushing for Canonical's Upstart to be widely adopted (and Fedora/RHEL used it too for a while). However, we eventually came to the conclusion that its design was inherently flawed at its core (at least in our eyes: most fundamentally, it leaves dependency management to the admin/developer, instead of solving this hard problem in code), and if something's wrong in the core you better replace it, rather than fix it. This was hardly the only reason though, other things that came into play, such as the licensing/contribution agreement mess around it. NIH wasn't one of the reasons, though..

Answer (score 0):

Actually...nope. As more and more of us who actually USE Linux and watch the Potterware train-wreck unfold we are moving to systemd free disto's.

http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

http://www.gabordemooij.com/index.php?p=/escape_from_systemd

The thread starter is from another tread response and is typical of the Microsoft like propoganda in support of systemd.

" I think one goal was to establish a single init-system among all major linux distributions (these have, currently, higher market share: ubuntu, centos, suse) – knb Aug 12 at 7:37 "

This is the attitude you might expect from a Microsoft or Apple engineer, it
has NO PLACE in linux. It is irritating to say this over and over...systemd
is NOT about init...its an abstraction layer much like that in Windows that
inposses itself between the Kernel and everything else. It is NOT about
starting your system...its about creating a situation where soon NOTHING
will run without systemd. Think about that for a minute....your system
will now be more vulernable an fragile....sound like linux ? Its not...